# Huawei Console - Select Testing Version "NO" not available

Tags: android, huawei-developers

my App was enabled for testing in Huawei Console. After finished the test period, I want do change test-version to production version. But that isn't possible.

In Huawei Console just using testing version `Yes` is selectable.

What is the problem?
[image]
Thanks,
GGK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to wait until the test phase you have defined is completed. then you can activate the version as a productive version